# Leaving comments next to the item signs in Enumerate environment like one can do in Theorem-alike environments?

Tags: enumerate

```
\documentclass{amsart}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[mean value theorem]
Item 1

\item
Item2
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I would like to leave a comment beside some item sign in Enumerate environment. A natural move is to mimic the method by which one can leave a comment next to, say "Theorem 1", in a theorem-alike environment. As we can see, however, this does not work.

So how to get it right? Specifically, I want to have

(1) [Mean value theorem]

(2)

without affecting the position of (1).

I have seen what I want in some textbooks that are highly possible edited by latex, so I am almost sure that what I want is doable in principle and therefore I have assumed in my question that it is doable.

Comment: What do you mean with "get it right"? Can you please clearly describe what the expected result would be?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry to confuse you. I hope the edited version "gets it right". @GonzaloMedina

Comment: Yes, now it's clear. Thanks for adding the additional information.

Comment: since a bracket immediately following `\item` is taken to mean a replacement for the index, if you want a bracket to appear, you need to "hide" it from the item-parsing mechanism.  the input `\item {[xxx]}`, or even `\item {[}xxx]` (brading just the opening bracket) will give the result you're looking for.  (this is a comment, because i'm sure this has been covered before.)

Comment: Dear @barbarabeeton, thank you so much; it solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since a bracket immediately following `\item` is taken to mean a replacement for the index, if you want a bracket to appear, you need to "hide" it from the item-parsing mechanism.

the input `\item {[xxx]}`, or even `\item {[}xxx]` (bracing just the opening bracket) will give the result you're looking for.

i'm sure this has been covered before, so if someone can find a duplicate, i'll expect this to be closed.